# Extending global sections uniquely when extending a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a family of smooth curves degenerating to a singular one. We might be interested in extending a $g_d^r$ on the (smooth) generic fiber of the family over the singular fiber. So let us focus on extending line bundles and their sections:

Let $\pi: X\to B$ be a family of projective curves over $\mathbb C$; we may assume $B$ is a smooth curve, so that $X$ is a surface (also smooth, if you wish), and $\pi$ is smooth except possibly over some closed point $b_0\in B$. Take the open subset $U=B\setminus\{b_0\}\subset B$ and suppose we are given a line bundle $L_U$ on $X_U$ and an extension $L$ to all of $X$ (that is, $L|_{X_U}\cong L_U$). I've found in the book "Limit linear series" by Brian Osserman the following phrase, which I do not understand:

> "There always exists a unique estension of the space of global
>   sections" $(\star)$

I think this means the following: there exists a unique $V\subset H^0(X,L)$ such that, if $V_U\subset H^0(X_U,L_U)$ is any subspace,  then $V|_{X_U}=V_U$, where $V|_{X_U}=V\cap H^0(X_U,L)$.

So here is what I would like to know:

1. Is my translation correct?
2. How to construct this unique extension? That is, how to prove $(\star)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you don't specify which book and provide more of the surrounding material for context?

Comment: I apologize for that; there was no reason to omit the title; I did not give much context because I think $(\star)$ is a quite general fact. Sorry again. I edited.

Comment: I would guess that the "exists" and the "for all" go the other way around. I.e., for all $V_U$ there exists a $V.$

Comment: That was my original guess. So perhaps it was the right one. Would you know how to prove the $(\star)$ assertion then?